# How do I check for Internet connection or load local file?

Tags: ios

I have an app which, from the app delegate, calls a synchronization engine. The synchronization engine fetches data from the web from a web service parses it and puts it in a core data base.

The individual you controllers call a fetch to the core database in order to present the data.

I want to add the feature of checking for Internet connectivity. Should I check for Internet connectivity in the app delegate and if there is one call the sync engine, else if there is not... What do I do, just leave it empty?

```
If (Internet) {
//call sync engine
} else { 
//do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for connectivity, there are a couple of options:

1. Use [Apple's Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class.  Easy to use, simple but isn't ARC compatible.
2. Use a 3rd party class that replaces Apple's.  [This one](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability#readme) is good.  ARC compatible.

Comment: Yes I am using reachability. But my question is how to handle using the local file instead of the web fetched file.

Comment: If you have structured both your local and web fetched file the same, you just need to put a conditional check for "Reachability". And then you can populate your model objects from that file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reachability? It works something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(networkChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

online = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[online startNotifier];

- (void)networkChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {

  NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [online currentReachabilityStatus];

  if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) { 
      //use local file
  }
  else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFiNetwork) { 
      //use remote file
  }
  else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork) { 
      //use remote file
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am using reachability. But my question is how to handle using the local file instead of the web fetched file.

Comment: @marciokoko See the edited answer above. Just use the local file when you are not connected to the internet.